# Resize inner control with dialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In mfc dialog based application i draw one graph on picture control and plot points as i needed,but problem is whenever i resize dialog that picture control remained as it is and looked weired! I can write some code on event of 0nSize() of dialog but it only resize other controls except picture control, so how to make changes on event of size changes of dialog?
 `

```
RECT rc;
   GetClientRect(&rc);
   rc.top+=25;
   rc.bottom-=80;
   rc.left+=15;
   rc.right+=15;

  GetDlgItem(IDC_PIC1)->MoveWindow(&rc);
```

Above i paste some code which i tried so much but not working,please give me any idea for that!

Comment: And what doesn't work with this code, except that the right side should be decreased instead of increased.

Comment: I think the problem is with your Drawing. Perhaps you draw using some constant values, e.g. the size of your chart is always "x" pixels regardless of the dialog size. I think you need to show us a few lines from your draw code

Comment: You used CWndResizer class and you can re-size your dialog. you can re-size control which you want go through this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125068/MFC-C-Helper-Class-for-Window-Resizing